# Where can I get a golem's heart?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm replaying Witcher 3 and I just noticed that I don't have the Golem's Heart ingredient needed for Enhanced Blizzard. I already did the early main quest where you fight a golem, but it seems that one didn't drop the ingredient.

Which monsters drop golem hearts and where can I find somewhat low-level ones? Are there any other ways to get hold of some golem hearts?

I would also accept cheats or console commands as answer if there is no easy way to get a golem's heart if the one early-game golem doesn't drop one.

Comment: There were a handful of side quests that featured Golems.  I think I got a heart out of the 3rd one I killed.

Answer (score 2):

All golem type enemies have a chance to drop Golem's Heart, although I personally have only found hearts in earth-type golems, but I'm not enough of a sample size.

In general I would suggest that before you encounter monsters that have rare drops needed for alchemy (Ekkimara, Nekker Warrior, Cave Troll, Cockatrice, Basilisk, and so on) you save your game and reload if you don't get the alchemy drop.